# Cannot import name 'TinyDB'

Tags: python, tinydb

I installed tinydb with pip.
`pip install tinydb`
I also tried it with pip3

I used the example code of tinydb to test it.

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('test.json')
db.insert({'int': 1, 'char': 'a'})
db.insert({'int': 1, 'char': 'b'})
```

but I get the importError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tinydb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
  File "/home/janw/Desktop/tinydb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
ImportError: cannot import name 'TinyDB'
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please be more specific what you did. Did you installed it in virtual environment or base environment. I tried to reproduce your code but it works fine at my end.

Comment: Hmm how could I explain. Like I start terminal and was on Desktop directory and installed it. And on my Desktop directory is also my py script. :/

Comment: in terminal type python as well as python3 and try to import it.
Do you have multiple versions of python installed try python and python3 to check versions

Comment: Thats strange when I use python 2 or 3 in terminal I can import it. Super strange

Comment: I tested on other device and it worked :/

Answer (score 5):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tinydb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
  File "/home/janw/Desktop/tinydb.py", line 1, in <module>
```

If you name your file tinydb.py then python will not be able to locate the actual TinyDB package. Very tricky mistake that a lot of beginners make :)

Answer (score -2):

I installed it using `pip install tinydb` and it worked for me. I'm able to import and use TinyDB.

Try removing it `pip uninstall tinydb` and installing it again.

If this doesn't work, try running `pip install --upgrade tinydb`. I hope this works.